# redux-form/immutable, how to update state in reducer.plugin?

Tags: redux, immutability, redux-form

currently I'm trying to use redux-form/immutable in ma brand new project and I'm facing so problems which I can't resolve (aspecially, with this cool reducer.plugin), probably couse I'm kinda new to immutable and stuff like that.

Appreciating and advice or help on topic.

so, first of all:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

import routing from './routeReducer';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
routing,
    form: formReducer.plugin({
        signupForm: (state, action) => {
            switch(action.type) {
                case 'SIGNUP_FACEBOOK':
                    return {
                        console.log(state);
                    }
                default:
                    return state
            }
        }
    })
});
```

while non of the forms field and touched this console.log(state) returns undefined, so here is the question: how may I initialize the form with some kind of state and actually update in on some sort of action ('SIGNUP_FACEBOOK' for this example)?

here is the form code sample:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import renderInputControl from '../../../common/InputControl';
import validate from './validate';

const SignUpForm = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting, invalid } = props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='signup__form'>
            <Field name='name' type='text' component={renderInputControl} label='Full Name'/>
            <Field name='email' type='email' component={renderInputControl} label='Email'/>
            <Field name='password' type='password' component={renderInputControl} label='Password'/>
            <Field name='tel' type='tel' component={renderInputControl} label='Phone Number'/>
            <button type='submit' disabled={submitting || invalid}>Sign Up</button>
         </form>
    );
};

SignUpForm.propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool,
    invalid: PropTypes.bool
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'signupForm',
    validate
})(SignUpForm);
```

and the second question is: even after I touch any of the fields (so it actually get some state, e.g. console.log(state) returns Map...), how should I update it, couse code:

```
state.getIn(['fields', 'name']).set('visited', false).set('touched', false)
```

which should set 'touched' and 'visited' to false doesn't do anything?

Best of luck!

Comment: I was kinda wrong, since with the empty form that first console.log(state) return a Map with "syncErrors" and "registeredFields".